# FaultException `1 was unhandled : Invalid Certificate?

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate

Building a client app to consume WCF protected by a cert. Cert is installed and can access the WSDL via IE but the app throws an "FaultException `1 was unhanded: Invalid Certificate" once it hits CaseExists. Any ideas? If the cert was invalid, wouldn't it error out when hitting the WSDL in IE?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // binding
            BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
            b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            // endpoint
            EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(
                "https://cut out endpoint.svc");

            // fire it up 
            EBondingClient client = new EBondingClient(b, ea);

            // toss in cert              
            client.ClientCredentials.Peer.PeerAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode =
                System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                StoreName.My,
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                "cut.out.cert.name");

            // call
            Console.WriteLine(client.CaseExists("hello world"));
            client.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The WSDL doesn't apply the same security as the actual service.  This is so consumers can access the schema of the service without having to know how to authenticate.

Comment: I would agree with you on that premise; but the guys who built this wsdl/wcf have the cert protecting the wsdl too. This is my first time dealing with wcf and only dealt with the traditional soap/wsdl stuff via javascript in class before this. my first reaction too was "why in the world do you need the cert installed to access the wsdl?" -- Is it possible the cert is valid for accessing the WSDL but not the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a typed fault exception (that's what ``` FaultException``1 ``` means). As far as I am aware, those can only be thrown explicitly by the server code. If the service host was detecting a certificate problem, it should be throwing a `MessageException`.

I would check the actual code of `CaseExists` to see if it throws and `FaultException<>` classes and begin there. Also, try catching `FaultException` and see what type of object the `Detail` property is, as that usually contains more information about the fault. (Specifically, each separate `FaultException<T>` concrete type will have a `public T Detail` property.)

Also, I don't *think* this related, but are you sure you need to be specifying a client-side certificate? That's separate from the server-side certificate that is protecting the service (and WSDL). It's unusual (though not unheard-of) for a server to require a client to supply a certificate, so I would confirm that you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look into this tommorow when I get to work. I'll let you know.